# WinInet undefined identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ftp, wininet

Im pretty new to c++ programming so bear with me . 
I'm trying to create a ftp client for educational purposes,
Did some research and decided to give Wininet a try and came across some online tutorials :

Take this as an example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
```

Note that there is no error checking or what so ever , this is just sample code.

```
int main(){

HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "server", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);  

...


InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); 

}
```

while writing this my ide(Vs2017) tells me "identifier internetOpenW is undefined". And the same with "InternetConnect".
I've been looking for a solution all over, with no succes !
I would appreciate any help , as i have nowhere else to turn to !

excuse my bad english !

Comment: is this the exact error? : 
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_InternetOpenA referenced in function main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WININET%2FInternetOpen);k(InternetOpen);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true)

Add "wininet.lib" here:
Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Don't forget to specify "wininet.lib" for both build configurations (Debug and Release).

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly ! i was able to figure it out . Next time i should take more time reading instead of asking ! i appreciate your reply regardlessly .